# How to reset a job status to inactive?

Tags: autosys

I have a job J1 which is dependent from the success of a job J0.
First time J0 failed so J1 is currently under status "failure".
This is fine.

Anyway I'd like now to reset its status so I can perform another test.
How to set J1's status from "FAILURE"  to "INACTIVE", in other words its initial status?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SENDEVENT -J J1 -E CHANGE_STATUS -s INACTIVE
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use below command. Question been asked long back, just answering so that other people can refer it !!

```
sendevent -E CHANGE_STATUS -s INACTIVE -J {job name}
```